# Tile 2 windows side by side by keyboard shortcuts

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard, window-manager

I am using `Mac OS X Lion 10.7.2`, often I like to display 2 windows side by side, does anyone know if there is any application which makes it possible to tile windows by simple keyboard shortcuts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Better Touch Tool](http://www.boastr.de/) to do that.

Here's an example configuration that has a keyboard shortcut for resizing to the right half and one for the left half. I also have a shortcut that quickly maximizes a window.
[image: Example BTT configuration]

Comment: Thanks for your comment... It seems that if I log out and log in, I need to reactive BTT, do you have any solution to keep it always activated?

Comment: Yes, in BTT, click General Settings, and then make sure "Launch BetterTouchTool on Startup" is checked.

Comment: I see, that works... BTW, is it a product still in Beta stage? Why isn't it in Apple Store?

Comment: See the author's blog posts about that - http://blog.boastr.net/?p=2229 and http://blog.boastr.net/?p=2698
So it's a stable app and works great, just not available in the mac app store.